# Does it make sense to index a table with just one column?

Tags: sql, t-sql, indexing, sql-server-2012

I wonder if it makes sense to index a table, which contains just a single column?  The table will be populated with 100's or 1000's of records and will be used to JOIN to another (larger table) in order to filter its records.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.  An explicit index probably does not make sense.  However, defining the single column as a `primary key` is often done (assuming it is never `NULL` and unique).

This is actually a common practice.  It is not uncommon for me to create exclusion tables, with logic such as:

```
from . . . 
where not exists (select 1 from exclusion_table et where et.id = ?.id)
```

A primary key index can speed up such a query.

In your case, it might not make a difference if the larger table has an index on the id used for the join.  However, you can give the optimizer of option of choosing which index to use.

Comment: I disagree. Index makes sense when you want to search. Search is used when you use WHERE clause or JOIN this table to other table(s).

Comment: Thank you all for your replies and explanations!  I failed to provide the details of my scenario, which is a list of ID's passed into a stored procedure -- I then load those into a temp table from passed in table-valued parameter.  I was asking about indexing that temp table.

Comment: @SQL_Guy . . . I would create the temporary table with a primary key on the column.  It should not hurt the resulting query and could be a significant boost.

Comment: I conducted a few experiments and, assuming that filtered table is much larger than the passed in list of values, the indexing doesn't seem to make a difference in this case.  The smaller list will always be scanned first (table scan or index scan) and then the larger table will have index seek performed against it, which is what one would expect.  There are might be other scenarios, where indexing would be beneficial, so I guess the conclusion is: test for your particular case.  Thank you all!

Comment: @SQL_Guy . . . It also depends on how you represent the logic connecting the two tables.

Comment: I am going to mark Gordon's reply as an answer since it was closest to what I was looking for, but again, thank you all for the feedback!

Comment: @SQL_Guy You should put a clustered index on it. Heaps have a tendency to behave erratically when joined in larger queries. Maybe in your test case index didn't help, but in the long run, it's better to be there and queries to go for index scan rather than table scan.

Comment: Bottom line (I hope everyone can agree) - There is no downside on having that index. It certainly not going to hurt any query. If it helps - great, if not - no harm. (time to create index on 1 column on 1000 rows should be insignificant)

Comment: Thank you, Nenad!  What you say makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

My vote is that it probably doesn't really make sense in your scenario. You're saying this table with a single column will be joined to another table to filter records in the other table, so why not just delete this table, index the other column in the other table, and filter that?

Essentially, why are you writing:

```
SELECT * FROM manycols M INNER JOIN singlecol s ON m.id = s.id WHERE s.id = 123
```

When that is this:

```
SELECT * FROM manycols m WHERE m.id = 123
```

Suppose the argument is that manycols has a million rows, and singlecol has a thousand. You want the thousand matching rows, it's manycols that would need to be indexed then for the benefit.

Suppose the argument is you want all rows except those in singlecol; you could index singlecol but the optimiser might choose to just load the entire table into a hash anyway, so again, indexing it wouldn't necessarily help

It feels like there's probably another way to do what you require that ditches this single column table entirely